# How to create a custom product view page in a custom url in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options, product-view, swatches

I need to create a custom product view page in a different custom url.

So, i created a custom module for this. But it didn't loads configurable, grouped, bundle swatches. Added the module below:

Override the product view controller

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" type="Tristar\ProductDetail\Controller\Product\View" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Product/View.php

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // Get initial data from request
        if(isset($_GET['proid'])){  
            $categoryId     =   (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
            $productId      =   $_GET['proid'];
            $specifyOptions =   $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');
        }else{
            $categoryId     =   (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
            $productId      =   (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $specifyOptions =   $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');
        }


        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->noProductRedirect();
            }
            if ($specifyOptions) {
                $notice = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
                $this->messageManager->addNotice($notice);
            }
            if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                $this->getResponse()->representJson(
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode([
                        'backUrl' => $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl()
                    ])
                );
                return;
            }
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        // Prepare helper and params
        $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

        // Render page
        try {
            $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productId, $this, $params);
            return $page;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $this->noProductRedirect();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('noroute');
            return $resultForward;
        }
    }
}
```

Here i get my product id from url, then passed that id through this controller.
Then added catalog_product_view.xml file same as this controller view

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customcatalog_product_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" />
        <attribute name="itemscope" value="itemscope"/>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Catalog::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
                <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
                <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                    <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                        <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                    <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                    <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" after="product.info.overview">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons.additional"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

When this url on browser passing with product id, http://customcatalog/product/view/?proid=8, i got all the view exact as product view view except the swatches area.

Comment: Let me know if you found the answer.